# Angularjs rating half stars

Tags: angularjs, rating

How can I achieve the half star in angular js.

For example:

If the value is between points like `2.3` it should display 2 full stars and one half star

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/manishpatil/2fahpk7s/

Comment: to achieve this, you should either have an image like that or try adding a css using :before or :after and add it dynamically

Comment: Can you update the fiddle?